# Undefined values displayed on page but localStorage is still present?

Tags: javascript, json

I apologize ahead of time, I'm new coding in general (particularly to localStorage) but I've tried everything I've come across--as far as I can understand the subject.

I'm using localStorage and JSON to parse data and I think I've got it "working." However, upon refresh/reload my displayed values become undefined. I have an array made with a push function adding a name and an incremented id. So let's say I add "a", "b", "c"--console it out and I get this (stored here: `localStorage.setItem("reminder")` (and `getItem` to fetch it, obviously)):

`"[{"id":0,"name":"a"},{"id":1,"name":"b"},{"id":2,"name":"c"}]"`

I know it's a string, so I parse that (like this: `JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("reminder"))`) and log it out to check--

```
0: {id: 0, name: "a"}
1: {id: 1, name: "b"}
2: {id: 2, name: "c"}
length: 3
__proto__: Array(0)
```

Then on my page, the list looks something like:

```
<ul id="list">
<li> a <span id="0"></span></li>
<li> b <span id="1"></span></li>
<li> c <span id="2"></span></li>
</ul>
```

Which is perfect. Until refresh, then it becomes:

```
<ul id="list">
<li> undefined <span id="3"></span></li>
<li> undefined <span id="3"></span></li>
<li> undefined <span id="3"></span></li>
</ul>
```

Which is, in fact, *not* perfect. But I can still log the string/array in console and get the values. I can also still go into Application -> localStorage and see my key("reminder") is still there and the values(as shown in the string previously stated) are also still present. Ignore the ids being list.length, I know I need to find a way to increment the ids instead of just being the total length--for now I'm more curious about my undefined situation.

Here's the whole chunk of code, the top-most being the localStorage focus.

```
/* VARIABLES */
var input;
var list;
var id;

/**********************************************************************
****************************** LOCAL **********************************
***********************************************************************/
//set  data
const reminderList = localStorage.getItem("reminder");

/* CHECKING */
if (!reminderList) {
    list = [];
    id = 0;
} else {
    list = JSON.parse(reminderList);
    id = list.length; //find way to iterate through id property
    readList(list);
}

/* LOAD DATA */
function readList(reminders){
    reminders.forEach(function(item){
        addReminder(item.name, item.id);
    });
};

/* EMPTY ALL */
document.getElementById("clearAll").addEventListener("click", function(){
    localStorage.clear();
    location.reload();
});

/**********************************************************************
***************************** FUNCTIONS *******************************
***********************************************************************/

/************************ PUSH TO ARRAY ************************/ 
function addReminder() {
    let content = `<li> ${input} <span id=${id} onclick="removeItem()"><i class="fa fa-trash-o de" id="trash"></i></span> </li>`;

    //add to displayList div
    document.getElementById("displayList").insertAdjacentHTML("beforeend", content);
};

    //click function
function addonClick() {
    input = document.getElementById('input').value;

    if (input === "") {
        alert("We can't remind you of nothing! Please try again.");
    } else {
    addReminder(name, id);

    //add to array
    list.push({
        id: id,
        name: input
    });

    //add to local data
    localStorage.setItem("reminder", JSON.stringify(list));
    console.log(JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("reminder"))); //checking to see if info is stored correctly(it is)

    id++;

    //reset input box
    document.getElementById('input').value="";
}};
```

Comment: `addReminder` is missing the parameters `input` and `id`.

Comment: Oops, you're right, I broke that function apart and forgot to put in parameters... but putting them in now makes my entries go blank. So the text inputs are empty, but the incremented id span is correct.